# JavaScriptSerializer Deserialize Throws System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, json

I use this below code while getting array of a PPTX file which is around 17 MB (This works fine if any file is less than 15 MB). At `jss.Deserialize` line it throws error "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException'"

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer { MaxJsonLength = 2147483644, RecursionLimit = 100 };

var requestJson = jss.Serialize(new { serverRelativeUrl = serverRelativeUrl, token = token });

WebClient wClient = new WebClient();
wClient.Headers["Content-Type"] = "text/json; charset=utf-8";

var data = wClient.UploadData(serviceMethodURL, "POST", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestJson));
var responseJson = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

var response = jss.Deserialize<MethodResponse<byte[]>>(responseJson);
```

Any idea? I am stuck with this. Please help

Comment: If you use JSON.NET for serialization/deserialization, you could substitute the default JsonValueProviderFactory with a custom one as shown in this blog post: http://www.dalsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2012/01/10/asp-net-mvc-3-improved-jsonvalueproviderfactory-using-json-net/

Comment: Thanx sagar but it's a windows form application, so Global.asax thing is not possible.

Comment: @Kaushal15 but JSON.NET is...

Comment: Are you able to switch to Json.NET for deserialization?  Also, what is the `MethodResponse<>` generic class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using

```
MethodResponse<byte[]> response = null;
using (System.IO.MemoryStream stream1 = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data))
{
    System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MethodResponse<byte[]>));
    stream1.Position = 0;
    response = (MethodResponse<byte[]>)ser.ReadObject(stream1);
}
return response;
```